# make etc/resolv.conf use secondary dns or rotate

Tags: macos, networking, dns

I have a local DNS server (bind9) configured to resolve the fqdm of several servers that I have in my local network, until here everything OK.

I put the ip of my local dns server and I can resolve the fqdm of my servers in my local network, but I can't surf the internet. I put the DNS of my internet provider next to the ip of my local DNS server (Bind9) , and I can only surf the internet I cannot resolve the names of any of my local servers.

I try to configure my mac the file resolv.conf (/etc/resolv.conf) adding the line:

-options timeout: 1 rotate attempts: 1

But this has no effect, I still can't resolve the fqdms of my local servers but I can navigate.

I restart the mac and I still cannot resolve the fqdm and also the entry created in resolv.conf has been deleted :(. Any idea how to configure the DNS in macOS so that they rotate and can use the two DNS servers.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not system configuration and troubleshooting; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask about this. But I can give you a short answer: macOS doesn't consult /etc/resolv.conf, so trying to configure it there doesn't do anything (see the note at the top of the file); also, macOS doesn't have a "rotate" policy like you want. If your private servers are under a unique TLD, you could create a file under /etc/resolver/ (those *do* work); search Ask Different for examples & how *not* to troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you have `forwarders` directive in your Bind config?

Comment: This question can likely be removed as I see the new post here with a solution that worked for @manuel-rando : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420717/macos-make-etc-resolv-conf-use-secondary-dns-or-rotate